# Page redirection not working in the ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I am tried to page redirect after login success. But My page not redirect proper page. I am getting `The connection was reset` error message. Please check my redirection code.

**routes.rb**

```
get    'login'   => 'users#login'
post   'login'   => 'users#create_login'
get   'my-profile'   => 'users#my_profile'
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def create_login
    user = User.authenticate(params[:user][:username], params[:user][:password])
    if user
      log_in user
      redirect_to 'my-profile'
    else
      flash[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
      redirect_to :back
    end
end

def my_profile
    @myProfile = User.findById(session[:user_id])
end
```

My page should be redirect to `http://localhost:3000/my-profile` but Page redirection not working. Please help me.

Comment: show your `routes`

Comment: try `redirect_to '/my-profile' `

Comment: ohh shit this is silly mistake here. Thank you @Sukanta

Comment: Can pass in flash messages in redirect: `redirect_to action: :my_profile, alert: "Invalid email/password combination"`.

Comment: @Chinu I have added answer, if this has solved your answer you can accept the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
redirect_to '/my-profile'
```

Comment: Routes might change down the road. It's better to stick with the action names. They usually change less. `redirect_to action: :my_profile`.

Comment: @Uzbekjon then I would rather do `get 'my-profile', to: 'users#my_profile', as: :profile_path` then `redirect_to profile_path`